# BATCH script, parsing several files with different extensions

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I need to automate a process creating a BATCH script. I must say my knowledge about BATCH scripting and programming in general is very very basic but i'm trying to learn.

I got an .exe with the next command line:

```
decrypt.exe -k [key of decrypt] -f [file for decrypt] -e [extension of file with dot]

example: decrypt.exe -k decrypt.key -f file.pdf -e .pdf
```

And i need to run it to decrypt thousands of files with different extensions.

My idea is to run the script on c:\ and recursively let it decrypt all the files.

Also, if the file has an extension .lol i need to rename the file removing only that extension, for example; file.pdf.lol to file.pdf. This is not as important, since i can just run a new script later.

So far this is what i got:

```
FOR /R %%f IN (*.lol) DO decrypt.exe -k "decrypt.key" -f "%%f" -e "%%~xf"
```

And after some investigation, i found the command FORFILES:

```
FORFILES /m *.lol /s /C "decrypt.exe -k decrypt.key -f @file -e @ext"
```

I got ALL the extensions writted on a .txt file, so if the script can read the extensions from that file would be great but i can't figure how.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /R %%f IN (*.lol) DO ren "%%f" "%%~nf"
FOR /R %%f IN (*.*) DO decrypt.exe -k "decrypt.key" -f "%%f" -e "%%~xf"
```

should work for you.

The first should rename the files from `*.lol` to `*` and then the second runs your `decrypt` according to your original code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

What about replacing the *.* on the second FOR and get/read the extensions i want from a .txt where i got them writted? would be too difficult?. Going on every file on the unit is too harsh :(

Comment: If you want to read from a file, use `for /f "delims=" %%f in (filename) do ...` You should try experiments against a copy of a subtree of your data files, just for safety's sake...